# In a C# ASP.NET Core 3.1 application how do I route to a controller then query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, parameter-passing, url-routing

I have a view setup as:

[image]

I then have my Business controller:

```
[Route("{business}/{url}")]
public IActionResult business(string url)
{
    return View();
}
```

My aim is to be able to pass the url string 'neatly' like so

```
https://website.com/business/business-name-123
```

The `business-name-123` is then received as the parameter.

I have created something similar to this before where you pass `?query=website-name` but I don't want this, can someone explain what I need to do to get this working using just the / routing aspect?

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with current setup?

Comment: Do you want to send requset in the form of  `https://website.com/business/business-name-123` instead of `https://website.com/business?Url=business-name-123` in view?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the braces around `{business}` in your route template. Business is a constant string, not a route parameter:

```
[Route("business/{url}")]
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you sir, easy when you know how :)